# Making a constructor which accepts std::string and returns hh::mm::ss format

Tags: c++, string, constructor

I need an implementation of a constructor that takes a string and returns a Duration object in the format hh:mm:ss.

```
#include <iostream>

class Duration {
private:
  int hours, minutes, seconds;

public:
  Duration() : hours(0), minutes(0), seconds(0) {}

  Duration(int s) : hours(s / 3600), minutes((s % 3600) / 60), seconds(s % 60) {}

  Duration(int h,int m,int s) : hours(h) , minutes(m), seconds(s){

     if (h < 0 || m < 0 || m > 59 || s < 0 || s > 59) {
      throw std::out_of_range("Invalid time format.");
    }
    }

  Duration(const Duration& other) : hours(other.hours), minutes(other.minutes), seconds(other.seconds) {}

  Duration(Duration&& other): hours(std::move(other.hours)), 
                              minutes(std::move(other.minutes)), 
                              seconds(std::move(other.seconds)) {}
  
  Duration& operator=(const Duration& other) {
    if (this != &other) {
      hours = other.hours;
      minutes = other.minutes;
      seconds = other.seconds;
    }
    return *this;
  }
```

I saw examples where they used std::regex, std::stoi but I am wondering if there is another simpler solution since I am a beginner. Thank you

```
Duration(const std::string& time_str) {
  std::regex pattern("(\\d{1,2}):(\\d{1,2}):(\\d{1,2})");
  std::smatch match;
  
  if (!std::regex_match(time_str, match, pattern)) {
    throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid time format");
  }
  
  int h = std::stoi(match[1]);
  int m = std::stoi(match[2]);
  int s = std::stoi(match[3]);
  
  if (h < 0 || h > 23 || m < 0 || m > 59 || s < 0 || s > 59) {
    throw std::out_of_range("Invalid time format");
  }
  
  hours = h;
  minutes = m;
  seconds = s;
}
```

Comment: If you have code that works that you want feedback on, Code Review Stack Exchange is a better fit: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Terminology: a constructor doesn't **return** anything. You're looking for a constructor that **creates an object** with certain properties.